i18next-resources-to-backend doesn't work for webpack prod build
I’m trying to set up i18n dynamic import for a library, so I have an init function:
import i18n from "i18next";
import resourcesToBackend from "i18next-resources-to-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(
    resourcesToBackend(
      (language: string, namespace: string) =>
        import(`locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
    )
  )
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    initImmediate: false,
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: "en",
    lng: "en",
    ns: ["checklist", "complexity"],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;

And the translations work when I import components from the library like this:
import {
  PasswordChecklist,
  PasswordComplexityIndicator,
  PasswordMeter,
  passwordStrength,
} from "../../src";

But i18n throws an errors when I try to import them from a production build folder:
Error: Cannot find module 'locales/en/checklist.json'
Error: Cannot find module 'locales/en/complexity.json'
import {
  PasswordChecklist,
  PasswordComplexityIndicator,
  PasswordMeter,
  passwordStrength,
} from "../../dist";

I expect all *.json files can be dynamically imported
